# Where should exceptions from validator interface be handled?

Tags: java, spring

In a web application I use Spring's Validator interface for validation.
There are some methods in the service layer for business logic, ex. to check username is valid, that are called by the validator class that throw exceptions.

Where should these exceptions be handled normally? I would prefer to add a throws clause in the validate method, but it won't let me.

Comment: maybe you need a `@ControllerAdvice`? https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring